# Perform FFT for every second on wav file with Python

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, wav, windowing

I have code which performs FFT on a 5 second wav file. I'm not good at Python so I wrote very basic code which splits the wav file and calculates FFT for every second. Is there any more convenient way to do this?

I'm also not sure if they show every frequency and its related amplitude because of the range part. I'm splitting a signal into 5 pieces but I might also split frequencies into 5 pieces also.

The variable names which end with numbers are my additions, normally I had only one for each of them to calculate whole FFT on wav. Any suggestion will be great. (I erased first second because of the bias, you should check the plot)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fs_rate, signal = wavfile.read("db1.wav")
#print ("Frequency sampling", fs_rate)
l_audio = len(signal.shape)
#print ("Channels", l_audio)
if l_audio == 2:
    signal = signal.sum(axis=1) / 2

signal2 = signal + 480000000    
N = signal2.shape[0]
#print ("Complete Samplings N", N)
secs = N / float(fs_rate)
#print ("secs", secs)
Ts = 1.0/fs_rate # sampling interval in time
#print ("Timestep between samples Ts", Ts)
t = scipy.arange(0, secs, Ts) # time vector as scipy arange field / numpy.ndarray

#FFT1 = abs(scipy.fft(signal2[0:44100]))
FFT2 = abs(scipy.fft(signal2[44100:88200]))
FFT3 = abs(scipy.fft(signal2[88200:132300]))
FFT4 = abs(scipy.fft(signal2[132300:176400]))
FFT5 = abs(scipy.fft(signal2[176400:220500]))

#FFT_side1 = FFT1[range(N//20)] # one side FFT range
FFT_side2 = FFT2[range(N//20)] # one side FFT range
FFT_side3 = FFT3[range(N//20)] # one side FFT range
FFT_side4 = FFT4[range(N//20)] # one side FFT range
FFT_side5 = FFT5[range(N//20)] # one side FFT range

#freqs1 = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(signal2[0:44100].size, t[1]-t[0])
freqs2 = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(signal2[44100:88200].size, t[1]-t[0])
freqs3 = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(signal2[88200:132300].size, t[1]-t[0])
freqs4 = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(signal2[132300:176400].size, t[1]-t[0])
freqs5 = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(signal2[176400:220500].size, t[1]-t[0])

#fft_freqs = np.array(freqs)

#freqs_side1 = freqs1[range(N//20)] # one side frequency range
freqs_side2 = freqs2[range(N//20)] # one side frequency range
freqs_side3 = freqs3[range(N//20)] # one side frequency range
freqs_side4 = freqs4[range(N//20)] # one side frequency range
freqs_side5 = freqs5[range(N//20)] # one side frequency range


#fft_freqs_side = np.array(freqs_side)

#abs(FFT_side1)
abs(FFT_side2)
abs(FFT_side3)
abs(FFT_side4)
abs(FFT_side5)

for a in range(60):
    #FFT_side1[a] = 0
    FFT_side2[a] = 0
    FFT_side3[a] = 0
    FFT_side4[a] = 0
    FFT_side5[a] = 0

plt.subplot(611)
p1 = plt.plot(t, signal2, "r") # plotting the signal
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

# plt.subplot(612)
# p3 = plt.plot(freqs_side1, FFT_side1, "b") # plotting the positive fft spectrum
# plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
# plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.subplot(613)
p3 = plt.plot(freqs_side2, FFT_side2, "g") # plotting the positive fft spectrum
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.subplot(614)
p3 = plt.plot(freqs_side3, FFT_side3, "g") # plotting the positive fft spectrum
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.subplot(615)
p3 = plt.plot(freqs_side4, FFT_side4, "g") # plotting the positive fft spectrum
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.subplot(616)
p3 = plt.plot(freqs_side5, FFT_side5, "g") # plotting the positive fft spectrum
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.show()
```

[image: Plots]

Comment: I'd suggest learning how to use `list`s and `for` loops!

Comment: The point is not `list` and `loop`. It shows same performance. In my code I'm not sure about FFT part. I split the signal but in each piece, is it really checking until 22050 Hz or did I split it also by mistake. I'm looking for it. `abs(scipy.fft(signal2... FFT2[range(N//20... scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(signal2... freqs2[range(N//20...` These are where I confused. @SamMason

Comment: Try the short time Fourier transform instead. `scipy.signal.stft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking can be accomplished in a single lane, by using the standard command for the [STFT](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html)

Comment: Couldnt configure it for my code, but guess correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Python example, which accepts any WAV and converts it to FFT by sample. Samples can be configured (`time_period`) to vary between 0.05 seconds and 10 seconds.

Output displays original sound (for the final sample), the FFT output (in buckets), a 1D image, and 2D image representation of the output.

[image: Code Output]

Python 3 Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import scipy
import scipy.fftpack
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

filename = "audio/pysynth_anthem.wav"
filename = "audio/pysynth_chopin.wav"
filename = "audio/menuet.wav"
filename = "audio/bach_violin.wav"

# ==============================================

time_period = 0.1 # FFT time period (in seconds). Can comfortably process time frames from 0.05 seconds - 10 seconds

# ==============================================

fs_rate, signal_original = wavfile.read(filename)
total_time = int(np.floor(len(signal_original)/fs_rate))
sample_range = np.arange(0,total_time,time_period)
total_samples = len(sample_range)

print ("Frequency sampling", fs_rate)
print ("total time: ", total_time)
print ("sample time period: ", time_period)
print ("total samples: ", total_samples)

output_array = []
for i in sample_range:

    print ("Processing: %d / %d (%d%%)" % (i/time_period + 1, total_samples, (i/time_period + 1)*100/total_samples))

    sample_start = int(i*fs_rate)
    sample_end = int((i+time_period)*fs_rate)
    signal = signal_original[sample_start:sample_end]

    l_audio = len(signal.shape)
    #print ("Channels", l_audio)

    if l_audio == 2:
        signal = signal.sum(axis=1) / 2
    N = signal.shape[0]
    #print ("Complete Samplings N", N)

    secs = N / float(fs_rate)
    # print ("secs", secs)
    Ts = 1.0/fs_rate # sampling interval in time
    #print ("Timestep between samples Ts", Ts)

    t = scipy.arange(0, secs, Ts) # time vector as scipy arange field / numpy.ndarray

    FFT = abs(scipy.fft(signal))
    FFT_side = FFT[range(int(N/2))] # one side FFT range
    freqs = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(signal.size, t[1]-t[0])
    fft_freqs = np.array(freqs)
    freqs_side = freqs[range(int(N/2))] # one side frequency range
    fft_freqs_side = np.array(freqs_side)

    # Reduce to 0-5000 Hz
    bucket_size = 5
    buckets = 16

    FFT_side = FFT_side[0:bucket_size*buckets]
    fft_freqs_side = fft_freqs_side[0:bucket_size*buckets]

    # Combine frequencies into buckets
    FFT_side = np.array([int(sum(FFT_side[current: current+bucket_size])) for current in range(0, len(FFT_side), bucket_size)])
    fft_freqs_side = np.array([int(sum(fft_freqs_side[current: current+bucket_size])) for current in range(0, len(fft_freqs_side), bucket_size)])

    # FFT_side: Normalize (0-1)
    max_value = max(FFT_side)
    if (max_value != 0):
        FFT_side_norm = FFT_side / max_value

    # Append to output array
    output_array.append(FFT_side_norm)

# ============================================

# Plotting

plt.figure(figsize=(8,10))

plt.subplot(411)
plt.plot(t, signal, "g") # plotting the signal
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.subplot(412)
diff = np.diff(fft_freqs_side)
widths = np.hstack([diff, diff[-1]])
plt.bar(fft_freqs_side, abs(FFT_side_norm), width=widths) # plotting the positive fft spectrum
plt.xticks(fft_freqs_side, fft_freqs_side, rotation='vertical')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Count single-sided')

FFT_side_norm_line = FFT_side_norm.copy()
FFT_side_norm_line.resize( (1,buckets) )

plt.subplot(413)
plt.imshow(FFT_side_norm_line)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Image Representation (1D)')

width_img = int(np.sqrt(buckets))
height_img = int(np.ceil(buckets / int(np.sqrt(buckets))))
FFT_side_norm_rect = FFT_side_norm.copy()
FFT_side_norm_rect.resize( (width_img,height_img) )

plt.subplot(414)
plt.imshow(FFT_side_norm_rect)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Image Representation (2D): %d x %d' % (width_img,height_img))

plt.show()

# =======================================================
```

Comment: Kind of late to this thread, which I just stumbled upon. I ran the above code, but FFT = abs(scipy.fft(signal)) resulted in the message "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Comment: @fishbacp `scipy.fft` refers to a SciPy submodule. For the action function, replace with `abs(scipy.fft.fft(signal))`.

Answer (score 1):

not played with FFTs in Python before, took the opportunity to play for a bit.  I recorded some audio — in Audacity as it also has nice built in FFT functionality so I had a nice reference to check that I was getting the "right" answer

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import fft
from scipy.io import wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# recording of me whistling at ~1.2 and 1khz
fs_rate, signal = wavfile.read("whistle-1170_970hz.wav")

# convert stereo to mono
signal = signal.mean(axis=1)

# generate time in seconds
t = np.arange(signal.shape[0]) / fs_rate

# plot everything
plt.plot(t, signal);

# create some plots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(
    2, sharex=True, sharey=True,
    figsize=(8, 6))

for ax, i in zip(axs, range(0, signal.shape[0], fs_rate)):
    # pull out sample for this second
    ss = signal[i:i + fs_rate]

    # generate FFT and frequencies
    sp = fft.fft(ss)
    freq = fft.fftfreq(len(ss), 1 / fs_rate)

    # plot the first few components
    ax.plot(freq[:2000], np.abs(sp.real[:2000]));
```

which gives plots peaks in the right place for me — plots at the bottom.  I'm having trouble following your repetition of code and repeated indexing operations, but think you're probably doing the right thing!

[image: matplotlib output]